# jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn issues

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'd like to filter portfolio thumbs with a few category links. Quicksand is too buggy, and I'd rather try to write my own code. I'm fairly new to jQuery, so I knew I'd run into issues, and probably excessive code. :)

I went ahead and created a jsFiddle showing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/zHWgG/1/

See how it flickers? The desired effect would be for me to click a filter, all visible fade out entirely, and then only the corresponding thumbs fade in. It's working and valid jQuery, but how can I:

1. get rid of the flickering effect
2. simplify/create a leaner code (less bytes)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything flicker in that demo...

Comment: What I'm seeing is double animations it seems, not sure. Does the fading out and then fading in of the category clicked seem smooth? Should look the same to everyone, hopefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use animation end callbacks.

```
$('.item').fadeOut(500, function() {
     $('.item').fadeIn(500);
});
```

**EDIT:**
The flickering occurs because non-visible .portfolio-itens are fadding-out – they become visible on effect activation. Try use this:

```
$('.portfolio-item:visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
     $('.item').fadeIn(500);
});
```

The pseudo-selector `:visible` will activate the fade-out only for the desired elements.

Comment: @JustinW Not on first anchor, that's the reason of my mistake. Excuse me.

Comment: That's actually pretty useful, thank you. Any compatibility issues with using the `:visible` pseudo-selector? If so, what would be another way of doing this? Also, it still flickers if I click a filter and then click "All". What should be changed there?

Comment: What kind of compatibility issues? I think jQuery implement the pseudo-selector in every browser.
And the "All" problem can be solved with my first answer.

Comment: You're right, I didn't have the callback on the first one.. Adding your answer with rrikesh's, this actually looks pretty smooth. Only thing now is, how do I get the code more simplified, if possible?

Comment: What about begin appling fading on "ul's" instead of "li's"?

Comment: Holy crap. Thank you so much. I've never seen an answer to this question (which is asked frequently) that includes the `:visible` selector. Turns out that's extremely important!

Comment: Hey, if it helped you out, be sure to upvote the question as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

To stop flickering, you should add `.stop()` to your code -> http://api.jquery.com/stop/

http://jsfiddle.net/rrikesh/dS5zV/

```
$('#all').click(function() {
        //fade out entire set (transition looks better)
        $('.portfolio-item').stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
            //fadeIn all thumbs
            $('.portfolio-item').fadeIn(500);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks again. Both answers have been very helpful. I'd like to check that you both answered, but tassoevan pretty much answered first..

Comment: No worries about that. My aim was to help you, not gather points :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to decrease the code:

```
    $('.menu_item').click(function(){
    var callBack = (function(itemsToShow){
        $('.portfolio-item:visible').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(itemsToShow).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });

    switch ($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'all':
            callBack('.portfolio-item');
            break;
        case 'web':
            callBack('.web');
            break;
        case 'graphic':
            callBack('.graphic');
            break;
        case 'logo':
            callBack('.logo');
            break;
        case 'motion':
            callBack('.motion');
            break;

    }                
});
```

As you can see from the above I added `menu_item` class to the navigation list

http://jsfiddle.net/zHWgG/18/

Comment: That really slims things down. I'll walk through this to better understand what's taking place here. Looks like my programming classes are coming back to me now! Thanks for your help, Ulan!

Comment: No problem! You can also try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zHWgG/23/
the only constraint here is that you have to have the same id name for navigation items and class name for the portfolio-item

Comment: That makes sense. I visualized something more along the lines of this example, as I wrote something like it with radio buttons a long time ago. I'm very rusty with my programming, so I needed that. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure what I did... now every javascript is broken, except for the Foundation Reveal plugin. If you know how I can get this working, please share your thoughts: http://justinjwilson.com. I'm such a novice, it's shameful :/

Comment: Just saying that you don't know what you did and asking for debugging is not sufficient. Try to use some sort of inspector like firebug or chrome's inspector to identify the problem. Then if still have some trouble post a new question.